# Passing a Value From an Experience Editor Button to PipelineProcessorControlStateRequest<ItemContext>

Tags: experience-editor, speak, ribbon

[Expanding on this question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/speak-disable-button-in-experience-editor-mode) I wanted to make the template id configurable so I can have different buttons active for different templates without duplicating that code. I created a new button in Sitecore that inherits from `/sitecore/templates/System/Ribbon/Large Button` which has a field called `Enabled On Template` but I can't find a way to pass this through the javascript and into the class that inherits from `PipelineProcessorControlStateRequest<ItemContext>`. I tried overriding the custom button's AddAttributes method and added the field's value as an attribute however it is not available in `context.button.attributes` in the `canExecute` method of my javascript. Is there a built in way to pass values from the button's item to a pipeline processor control state request?

Here's what I tried that didn't work:

```
namespace Common.CustomSitecore.Speak.Controls
{
    public class UpdateButton : Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.LargeButton.LargeButton
    {
        public UpdateButton(RenderingParametersResolver renderingParametersResolver) : base(renderingParametersResolver)
        {
        }

        protected override void InitializeControl(RenderingParametersResolver resolver)
        {
            if(ResolveContentItem()?.TemplateId != "{MyId}")
               this.IsVisible = false;

            base.InitializeControl(resolver);
        }

        protected override void AddAttributes(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            //I also tried prefixing this with "data-sc-" because the html for 
            //attributes that the button ends up having seem to have that
            output.AddAttribute("EnabledOnTemplate", DataSourceItem[Constants.EnabledOnTemplateFieldId]);

            base.AddAttributes(output);
        }
    }

    public static class ControlsExtension
    {
        public static HtmlString UpdateButton(this Sitecore.Mvc.Controls controls, Rendering rendering)
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(controls, "controls");
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(rendering, "rendering");
            var largeButton = new UpdateButton(controls.GetParametersResolver(rendering));
            return new HtmlString(largeButton.Render());
        }
    }
}
```

Js:

```
define(["sitecore", "/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js"], function (Sitecore, ExperienceEditor) {
    Sitecore.Commands.MyCustomCommand =
    {
        canExecute: function (context) {
            if (!ExperienceEditor.isInMode("edit")) {
                return false;
            }
            //Here I wanted to read the attribute I added however it does not
            //seem to be attached to the button. After that I was going to create a
            //new item context to use the with the request but since I can't even 
            //seem to read it here I think this approach is a dead end because
            //context.button.attributes.EnabledOnTemplate is undefined
            context.currentContext.EnabledOnTemplate = context.button.attributes.EnabledOnTemplate;

            return context.app.canExecute("Custom.CanExecute", context.currentContext);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like a ton of hacking to pass some parameters. I opted to pass the ribbon id instead of individual field values because I ended up needing more parameters.

Adding the id of the ribbon button to attributes:

```
namespace Common.CustomSitecore.Speak.Controls
{
    public class UpdateButton : Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.LargeButton.LargeButton
    {
        public UpdateButton(RenderingParametersResolver renderingParametersResolver) : base(renderingParametersResolver)
        {
        }

        protected override void InitializeControl(RenderingParametersResolver resolver)
        {
            if(ResolveContentItem()?.TemplateId != "{MyId}")
               this.IsVisible = false;

            base.InitializeControl(resolver);
        }

        protected override void AddAttributes(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            //I also tried prefixing this with "data-sc-" because the html for 
            //attributes that the button ends up having seem to have that
            output.AddAttribute("data-sc-ribbonButton", DataSourceItem.ID.ToString().UrlEncode());

            base.AddAttributes(output);
        }
    }

    public static class ControlsExtension
    {
        public static HtmlString UpdateButton(this Sitecore.Mvc.Controls controls, Rendering rendering)
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(controls, "controls");
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(rendering, "rendering");
            var largeButton = new UpdateButton(controls.GetParametersResolver(rendering));
            return new HtmlString(largeButton.Render());
        }
    }
}
```

Accessing it and passing it to the request via javascript:

```
define(["sitecore", "/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js"], function (Sitecore, ExperienceEditor) {
    Sitecore.Commands.MyCustomCommand =
    {
        canExecute: function (context) {
            if (!ExperienceEditor.isInMode("edit")) {
                return false;
            }

            var button = ExperienceEditor.Common.getElementById(context.button.attributes.name);

            context.currentContext.ribbonButton = button.attributes["data-sc-ribbonButton"].nodeValue;
            return context.app.canExecute("Custom.CanExecute", context.currentContext);
        }
    };
});
```

Custom context for the request:

```
namespace Common.CustomSitecore.Speak.Server.Contexts
{
    public class RibbonButtonItemContext : ItemContext
    {
        [JsonProperty("ribbonButton")]
        public string RibbonButton { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore] private Item ribbonItem;

        //This is basically copied from the Item property with the id used updated and db 
        //that the item is pulled from updated
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Item RibbonButtonItem
        {
            get
            {
                if (ribbonItem != null)
                    return ribbonItem;
                //This might be a dangerous move! There is a database name passed but it's for 
                //the current content item. It might be worth routing this through as an 
                //attribute like the id
                var database = Factory.GetDatabase("core");
                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsNotNull(database, "Could not get database, with name core");
                ID result;
                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue((ID.TryParse(RibbonButton, out result) ? 1 : 0) != 0, "Could not get item with id:{0} from database: core", RibbonButton);
                if (Language == null)
                    Language = Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.ClientLanguage;
                var language = (Sitecore.Globalization.Language)null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Language))
                    language = LanguageManager.GetLanguage(this.Language);
                var version = GetVersion(Version);
                if (language != null && version != null)
                    ribbonItem = database.GetItem(result, language, version);
                if (ribbonItem == null && language != null)
                    ribbonItem = database.GetItem(result, language);
                return ribbonItem ?? (ribbonItem = database.GetItem(result));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Request using the custom context:

```
namespace Common.CustomSitecore.Requests.SharedContent
{
    public class CanExecute: PipelineProcessorControlStateRequest<ItemContext>
    {
        public override bool GetControlState()
        {
            //we now have access to RequestContext.RibbonButton which can be used to get 
            //the ribbon button item from core
            return base.RequestContext.Item.InheritsFrom(Constants.MyTemplateID);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see this is not really supported without hacking Sitecore.
The LargeButton has his own `.js` and `.cshtml` which is collecting the properties from the *core* database. Exactly in the following folder: `\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Controls\LargeButton`.

If you have look in the `LargeButton.cshtml` then you can see it uses the `LargeButton` class from the `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.LargeButton`.

### What you could do

Create your own button based on the `LargeButton`, you need the following then:

1. Create the button rendering item in *core* database based on `/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceEditor/Common/Layouts/Renderings/Ribbon/LargeButton` item
2. Create your own `.cshtml` and `.js` based on the files what I mentioned above
3. Implement your own Ribbon Control at the end where you can have access to the Rendering Parameters and add new attributes, something like this:

   ```
   public class CustomLargeButton : RibbonIconButtonBase
   {
       public CustomLargeButton()
       {
       }

       public CustomLargeButton(RenderingParametersResolver parametersResolver)
           : base(parametersResolver)
       {
       }

       protected override void InitializeControl(RenderingParametersResolver parametersResolver)
       {
           base.InitializeControl(parametersResolver);
           this.Attributes["data-sc-mycustomattribute"] = renderingParametersResolver.GetString("MyCustomAttribute", string.Empty);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: How do I actually access the value set on `data-sc-mycustomattribute` in my class that inherits `PipelineProcessorControlStateRequest<ItemContext>` in the linked question? Note that the code block with the class `UpdateButton` is already my custom ribbon button. I see the attributes set in the js when doing it the way I have it, I'm just not positive how to get them and then send them to ee requests (i.e. `Custom.CanExecute`).

Comment: @Teeknow you are right, I did not read it carefully. I will recheck.

Comment: I can't edit my comment at this point but I meant I see the attributes in the html. I'm not able to get them in the js through `context.button.attributes`.